# About casting and objects

Tags: object, c#-3.0, types, casting, type-safety

it's simple, i just want a explanation about this:

```
internal class B { // Base class
}
internal class D : B { // Derived class
}
```

in other class I wrote:

```
B b3 = new Object(); //compilation time error!
```

why??? We suposse that all  classes inherit from "object"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is more specialized than `Object`, therefore you cannot assign an `Object` instance to a `B` reference. This is because not every `Object` is actually a `B` - only the opposite is true.

Let's assume that you have a field `x` in the class `B`. When you instantiate an `Object`, no memory is reserved for this field, and if you could assign it to a reference of type `B`, it would therefore try to read or write to unallocated memory, which is not allowed (or useful).

Answer (score 2):

All classes are `object`s, but not all objects are `{someclass}`.

In a similar way, all buses are vehicles, but not all vehicles are buses.